# Can Memgraph be accessed with various drivers?

Tags: memgraphdb

I am using Memgraph Platform Docker image 2.6.0, and I want to connect to the running Memgraph instance using Python and JavaScript. Is it possible to connect to Memgraph with various drivers? I have been using only GQLAlchemy for Python so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to query Memgraph programmatically, you can do so using the Bolt protocol. The Bolt protocol was designed for efficient communication with graph databases and Memgraph supports versions 1 and 4 of the protocol. Memgraph has Bolt protocol drivers for the following programming languages: Python, C/C++, Rust, Node.js, C#, Go, Haskell, Java, JavaScript, PHP and Ruby. Here is the [JavaScript quick start guide](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/javascript), so that you can quickly connect to a running Memgraph instance.